# Expression must have pointer type error on a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

So I am creating a program that *must* use 2D dynamic arrays to add/multiply/subtract matrices. I have gotten through the whole program but my destructor is giving me some issues. When trying to deallocate memory I am getting the error "Expression must have pointer type" even though I believe it is already a pointer? Help would be much appreciated.

class:

```
#ifndef matrixType_H
#define matrixType_H

class matrixType
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& osObject, const matrixType& cObject);

public:
    void setValues(int**, int**, int, int, int, int);
    void addMatrices();
    void subtractMatrices();
    void multiplyMatrices();
    void printMatrix();
    matrixType operator+(const matrixType& object);
    matrixType operator-(const matrixType& object);
    matrixType operator*(const matrixType& object);
    const matrixType& operator=(const matrixType& object);
    matrixType(const matrixType& object);
    matrixType();
    ~matrixType();

private:
    int row1;
    int row2;
    int col1;
    int col2;
    int **matrixPointer1;
    int **matrixPointer2;

};

#endif
```

As requested, function that will "set" my pointers after taking user input from the source file. The source file also contains 2 int** pointers that i copy into the class

```
void matrixType::setValues(int **matrix1, int **matrix2, int r1, int r2, int c1, int c2)
{
    row1 = r1;
    row2 = r2;
    col1 = c1;
    col2 = c2;

    matrixPointer1 = matrix1;
    matrixPointer2 = matrix2;
}
```

Function giving me issues:

```
matrixType::~matrixType()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < col1; j++)
            delete[]matrixPointer1[i][j]; //Error: Expression must have pointer type

        delete[]matrixPointer1[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row2; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < col2; j++)
            delete[]matrixPointer2[i][j]; //Error: Expression must have pointer type

        delete[]matrixPointer2[i];
    }

    delete[]matrixPointer1;
    delete[]matrixPointer2;
}
```

Comment: Since you define `matrixPointer1` as `int**`, then dereferencing it twice (i.e. `matrixPointer1[i][j]` will give you an `int`, which is not a pointer type.

Comment: Then what should be the proper way to deallocate this memory? Removing the lines with the error causes my program to go out of bounds (although it works without the destructor)

Comment: Where is the code where you allocate the array in the first place?

Comment: Editing main problem now to include the "set" function.

Comment: That's the code where you assign the pointers. But where do you actually allocate the memory (i.e. where do you call `new int[][]`?)

Comment: It is probably a good idea to do the allocation of that array in the same object/scope which does the deallocation. My suggestion would be to allocate those arrays in the constructor of `matrixType`. Using `set()` is probably unnecessary.

Comment: Solely in my constructor which I realize is probably a mistake on my part!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't provided the code where you allocate the memory, I can only give you a pretty good guess:

I assume that somewhere outside of `matrixType`, you are doing something to the effect of:

```
int** matrix = new int[width];
for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
{
    matrix[i] = new int[height];
}
```

In that case, a matching deallocation would look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
{
    delete[] matrix[i];
}

delete[] matrix;
```

Note that spreading out the "ownership" of the `matrix` pointer is bad practice, and can lead to all kinds of problems later on. As your program becomes more complicated, it becomes more difficult to keep track of who is using what memory, and you'll probably end up freeing a pointer that gets dereferenced later on (leading to a segfault, or undefined behavior).

A good rule of thumb is to keep ownership of memory within the scope that created it.

For example, if you have an object that allocates some memory, the destructor for that object should be responsible for freeing it:

```
// example
class Vector
{
public:
     Vector(int size)
     { data = new int[size]; }

     ~Vector()
     { delete[] data; }

private:
     int* data;
};
```

Similarly, if you allocate some memory in a function, and then pass a pointer to another function or scope, the creating function should be responsible for freeing that memory:

```
// example
void foo()
{
    int* an_array = new int[10];
    process_array(an_array);
    delete[] an_array; // <-- we allocated in this scope, so we free in this scope
}
```